# Extracting part of string by position in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of strings string which look like this

```
ABC_EFG_HIG_ADF_AKF_MNB
```

Now from each of this element I want to extract the 3rd set of strings(from left) i.e in this case HIG. How can I achieve this in R

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `sub`.  We match one or more characters that are not `_` (`[^_]+`) followed by a `_`.  Keep it in a capture group.  As we wants to extract the third set of non `_` characters, we repeat the previously enclosed group 2 times (`{2}`) followed by another capture group of one or more non `_` characters, and the rest of the characters indicated by `.*`.  In the replacement, we use the backreference for the second capture group (`\\2`).

```
sub("^([^_]+_){2}([^_]+).*", "\\2", str1)
#[1] "HIG"
```

---

Or another option is with `scan`

```
scan(text=str1, sep="_", what="", quiet=TRUE)[3]
#[1] "HIG"
```

A similar option as mentioned by @RHertel would be to use `read.table/read.csv` on the string

```
 read.table(text=str1,sep = "_", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[,3]
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "ABC_EFG_HIG_ADF_AKF_MNB"
```

Answer (score 20):

`substr` extracts a substring by position:

```
substr('ABC_EFG_HIG_ADF_AKF_MNB', 9, 11)
```

returns

```
[1] "HIG"
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's one more possibility:

```
strsplit(str1,"_")[[1]][3]
#[1] "HIG"
```

The command `strsplit()` does what its name suggests: it splits a string. The second parameter is the character on which the string is split, wherever it is found within the string.

Perhaps somewhat surprisingly, `strsplit()` returns a list. So we can either use `unlist()` to access the resulting split parts of the original string, or in this case address them with the index of the list `[[1]]` since the list in this example has only one member, which consists of six character strings (cf. the output of `str(strsplit(str1,"_"))`). 
To access the third entry of this list, we can specify `[3]` at the end of the command.

The string `str1` is defined here as in the answer by @akrun.

Comment: Was about to post the same, but slightly different: `strsplit(str1,"_")[[c(1,3)]]`, just to show what a vector does inside `[[`.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the place of the pattern you look for, and you know that it is fixed (here, between the 9 and 11 character), you can simply use str_sub(), from the stringr package.

```
MyString = 'ABC_EFG_HIG_ADF_AKF_MNB'
str_sub(MyString, 9, 11)
```

Answer (score 2):

A new option is using the function `str_split_i` from the development version [stringr](https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/blob/main/NEWS.md) which can also extract a string by position split by a certain string. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
# devtools::install_github("tidyverse/stringr")
library(stringr)
x <- c("ABC_EFG_HIG_ADF_AKF_MNB")
str_split_i(x, "_", 3)
#> [1] "HIG"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see it extracted the third string. If you want the 6th you can change the 3 with 6 like this:

```r
library(stringr)
x <- c("ABC_EFG_HIG_ADF_AKF_MNB")
str_split_i(x, "_", 6)
#> [1] "MNB"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>